# How can I depend upon a CMake project's built targets from its build tree? And why is my attempt to find_package from its build tree not working?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have compiled some open source app and didn't install using `make install`, so the executable are still in the build path:

```
/home/vagrant/oatpp/build/src
vagrant@vagrant:~/oatpp/build/src$ find . -name "*.a"
./liboatpp-test.a
./liboatpp.a
vagrant@vagrant:~/oatpp/build/src$
```

Now I like to compile app which links with this lib using simple starter app which its CMakefile looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
 "/home/vagrant/oatpp/")
set(project_name my-project) ## rename your project here

project(${project_name})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(${project_name}-lib
        src/AppComponent.hpp
        src/controller/MyController.cpp
        src/controller/MyController.hpp
        src/dto/DTOs.hpp
)

## link libs

find_package(oatpp 1.3.0 REQUIRED PATHS /home/vagrant/oatpp/build/src /home/vagrant/oatpp/build/ /home/vagrant/oatpp/)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-lib
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp-test
)

target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC src)

## add executables

add_executable(${project_name}-exe
        src/App.cpp
        test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)

add_executable(${project_name}-test
        test/tests.cpp
        test/app/TestComponent.hpp
        test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp
        test/MyControllerTest.cpp
        test/MyControllerTest.hpp
)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)
set_target_properties(${project_name}-lib ${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-test PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 11
        CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)

enable_testing()
add_test(project-tests ${project_name}-test)
```

When compiling I'm getting:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/oatpp-starter/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /home/vagrant/oatpp/build/src/oatppConfig.cmake:18 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /home/vagrant/oatpp/build/src/oatppTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)


CMake Error at /home/vagrant/oatpp/build/src/oatppConfig.cmake:11 (message):
  File or directory /home/vagrant/include/oatpp-1.3.0/oatpp/ referenced by
  variable oatpp_INCLUDE_DIRS does not exist !
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/vagrant/oatpp/build/src/oatppConfig.cmake:21 (set_and_check)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

How can I set the searching paths for cmake?

Comment: "How can i set the searching paths for cmake?" - You are set searching paths for `find_package` so it takes the file `oatppConfig.cmake` ... which is intended to be used from the **install tree**. This doesn't work. Instead, install the project (`make install` from build directory of `oatpp`) so `find_package` will be able to find `oatppConfig.cmake` in the installation tree. (Note, that you could install the package into the custom location, by specifying `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/custom/directory` when configure it.)

Comment: if it is just to compile current project you can use [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html) with known location. otherwise add dependency in your project as a third-party and compile it with master project, then you can use targets provided by `oatpp`. as a last try - install `oatpp` in some particular place (not in system) and then just use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH pointing to this installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project you want to depend upon from its build directory exported its targets using the [`export`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html) command, then you could [`include`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) the targets file to depend upon the target outputs from that build directory. If you hardcode a relative path or absolute path, that's a bit brittle because it presumes on a specific relative/absolute location of that build directory being depended upon. If that kind of brittleness is a concern, you could pass that build directory as a cache variable using [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D) and then use that variable in the `include` call.

In that same scenario, I think you could also write [a find module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-modes) that just wraps a similar call to `include`.

Or you could just go and [run installation on the dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project) and then use `find_package`- assuming that the dependency provides a find-config script for installations.

As for the error message you got, it's because `find_package` managed to find [the configured/generated version of a config file for the package](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/blob/e33e6d567e449e66ea25466e01928ce5af91cec9/cmake/module-install.cmake#L98) that [gets copied to the install tree during installation](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/blob/e33e6d567e449e66ea25466e01928ce5af91cec9/cmake/module-install.cmake#L111) and is supposed to be used after installation is run. Of course there is no targets file because [the targets file is created when installation is run](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/blob/e33e6d567e449e66ea25466e01928ce5af91cec9/cmake/module-install.cmake#L82). It's an unfortunate and confusing scenario to run into if you don't really know what you're doing.